# GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN) returning incorrect height?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I'm attempting to get the width and height of the primary monitor via `GetSystemMetrics`. However, calling:

```
GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
```

Is returning a value of `1018`, rather than the actual vertical resolution, which is `1080`.

Now, I thought maybe I misunderstood the docs, so I tried calling

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA)
```

to see if maybe that was actually the one that gave the full screen. But, it does as it describes, and returns the working area of the screen (total_height - taskbar_height). Which in my case is 1040 pixels (1080 - 40 (taskbar height)).

So, I'm a bit stumped. Where is 1018 coming from? What's causing it to be off by 62 pixels?

Comment: Do you have more than one screen?

Comment: You can try `SM_CYSCREEN` instead of `SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN`

Comment: Works here all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)` should do the job.

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this is equal to `GetDeviceCaps(hdcPrimaryMonitor, VERTRES)` which might be what you really want.

Comment: Doh! Missed that one while browsing the MSDN. I wish they'd group the related flags together! Thanks a bunch.